# Insert Button Not working after verifying duplicate entry

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, wamp

Hi I am beginner I am trying to create a reservation system somehow I can check now if there is duplicate entry  however if there's no duplicate entry it is not inserting the data into the database but it if I remove my function to check the duplicate it can insert the data in database. Any suggestion? I am trying to figure it out but it still not working.No error but not adding.

```
  private void btnreserveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     try {
        DB_Operation DB =new DB_Operation();
        String cx1,contactnum11,email1,t11,venuee;
        String amount1=aval.getText();
        String bal1=b1.getText();
        cx1=cx.getText();
        contactnum11=contactnum1.getText();
        email1=email.getText();
        t11=t1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        venuee=v.getSelectedItem().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String Dateee = sdf.format(dad.getSelectedDate().getTime());
        boolean unique;
        unique = true;

        String c1="8am to 12 pm";
        String c3="8am to 5pm";
        String c2="1pm to 5 pm";
        ResultSet rsa= DB.searchQuery("SELECT * FROM `reserve1` WHERE `Date`='"+Dateee+"'");
        if ( cx.getText().trim().length() == 0||  contactnum1.getText().trim().length() == 0||email.getText().trim().length() == 0){
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "All fields must be completed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
        else if(rsa.isBeforeFirst()){
            while(rsa.next()){


                if(rsa.getString("Venue").equalsIgnoreCase(venuee)&&
                        rsa.getString("Date").equalsIgnoreCase(Dateee)&& rsa.getString("Time").equals(t11)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Duplicate Resevation!");
                    unique = false;
                }
                else if((t11.equals(c3))&&(rsa.getString("Venue").equalsIgnoreCase(venuee)&&
                        rsa.getString("Date").equalsIgnoreCase(Dateee)&& rsa.getString("Time").equals(c1))){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Half Day Resevation Exist!");
                    unique = false;
                }
                 else if((t11.equals(c3))&&(rsa.getString("Venue").equalsIgnoreCase(venuee)&&
                        rsa.getString("Date").equalsIgnoreCase(Dateee)&& rsa.getString("Time").equals(c2))){
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Half Day Resevation Exist!");
                    unique = false;
                }
                else if(unique=true){
                    try
 {

     String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
    String userdb="root";
    String passdb="";  

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userdb,passdb);

     Statement stmt=(Statement)conn.createStatement();

      stmt.executeUpdate ("INSERT INTO `reserve1`( `Customer Name`, `Contact Number`, `Email Address`, `Venue`, `Date`, `Time`, `Price`, `Balance`) "+ "VALUES ("+"\""+cx1+"\""+","+"\""+contactnum11+"\""+","+"\""+email1+"\""+","+"\""+venuee+"\""+","+"\""+Date1+"\""+","+"\""+t11+"\""+","+"\""+amount1+"\""+","+"\""+bal1+"\""+")");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Added!");


 }
 catch(        HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
 {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage() ,"Error", 1);


 }


                }
            }
        }
      }    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(reservation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
     null, ex);
      }
```

Comment: Can you provide result set for your query:
SELECT * FROM `reserve1` WHERE `Date`='"+Dateee+"'"
and for the values for venuee,Dateee and t11

Comment: It will check if the selected date is in the database and what venue been reserve and what time if the inputted data is equal to the date,venue,time in database it is displaying message "Duplicate Reservation"

Comment: I think that values your are going to provide by GUI. please show the value your are passing and the result for your query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put the `if(unique=true)` as a separate if statement and not as the part of else if ladder.

Comment: thank you very much for help. I did solved it by placing some }} before else and it worked :) thank you again